# Exclude count for html spacing

Tags: php

I have following two `div` tags and would like to count only words/character that are human readable.

```
<div>Pickup</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

When I use PHP `strlen()` , they both return a same value and I cannot use it to show only the Pickup.
Same scenario when I use `str_word_count()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you reading the text inside the divs>? Using a DOM Parser? Using a RegEx?

Comment: using just a normal php. Here is my code to read them.                     $field_str_len = strlen(trim($input_fields[$field->field_name]->input));

Comment: where $input_fields[$field->field_name]->input produce <div>Pickup</div> and <div>&nbsp;</div> with different parameter

Answer (score 0):

First decode html entities and remove all html tags:

```
$text = '<div>Pickup</div>';
echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($text)); // This show up "Pickup" only
```

Then count words:

```
str_word_count($text); // This should return 1
```

Comment: I want to maintain the div tag, just want to get rid of the &nbsp;